# C - Read input from text file (int,string,int,int)

Tags: c, csv, file, txt, file-manipulation

First of all sorry for any english error.
So, I have this data in a .txt file

```
Codigo,Produto,StockMinimo,StockAtual
1,Couro,300,1000
2,Tecido,250,2000
...
```

I want to skip the first line and read only the integers to a struct

I'm using the bellow function to count the line of the file:

```
int nrLinhasFicheiro(char *filename){
    char ch;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int linhas = 0;
    if (file != NULL) {
         for (ch = getc(file); ch != EOF; ch = getc(file)) 
        if (ch == '\n')  
            linhas = linhas + 1; 
    }
    fclose(file);
    return linhas - 1;
}
```

and this one to read the file to the struct "Stock" :

```
void carregarStock(Stock *stock, char *nomeFicheiro){
    int i = 0;
    int codigo; //stores "codigo" values
    char stringFake[40], *storeProduto; //variables to store first line and "Produto" string
    int minimo, quantidade;
    
    FILE *fp = fopen(nomeFicheiro, "r");
    
    int numeroLinhas = nrLinhasFicheiro(nomeFicheiro);
    
    if (fp != NULL){
       
        if(numeroLinhas >0){
            fscanf(fp, "%s",stringFake);//skip first line
            
            while(i< numeroLinhas){
                fscanf(fp, "%d,%s ,%d,%d", &codigo, storeProduto, &minimo, &quantidade);
                //fscanf(fp, "%d,%s %d,%d", &codigo, storeProduto, &minimo, &quantidade);  also tried this and don't work
                
                if(codigo==1){
                    stock->minStockCouro = minimo;
                    stock->couroStock = quantidade;
                }else if(codigo==2){
                    stock->minStockTecido = minimo;
                    stock->tecidoStock = quantidade;
                }else if(codigo==3){
                    stock->minStockBorracha = minimo;
                    stock->borrachaStock = quantidade;
                }else if(codigo==4){
                    stock->minStockCordoes = minimo;
                    stock->cordoesStock = quantidade;
                }else if(codigo==5){
                    stock->minStockPalmilhas = minimo;
                    stock->palmilhasStock = quantidade;
                }   
                i++;
            }
            
        }else{
            puts("Error");          
        }      
    }else{
        puts(MSG_ERRO_LER_FICHEIRO);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Function to print the struct:

```
void mostrarStock(Stock stock){
    puts("==============  Stock : =============\n");
    puts("Codigo | Produto | Stock Minimo | Stock Atual\n");
    printf("1\tCouro\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", stock.minStockCouro, stock.couroStock);
    printf("2\tTecido\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", stock.minStockTecido, stock.tecidoStock);
    printf("3\tBorracha\t%d\t\t%d\n", stock.minStockBorracha, stock.borrachaStock);
    printf("4\tCordões\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", stock.minStockCordoes, stock.cordoesStock);
    printf("5\tPalmilhas\t%d\t\t%d\n", stock.minStockPalmilhas, stock.palmilhasStock);

}
```

This is how i call the function in main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    char *nomeFicheiro1 = "tabela_stocks.txt";
    Stock stock;
    carregarStock(&stock, nomeFicheiro1);
    mostrarStock(stock);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The function to print the struct doesn't print.
I guess the error is in

```
fscanf(fp, "%d,%s ,%d,%d", &codigo, storeProduto, &minimo, &quantidade);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "I run the project it appears "Run Successful" but either the info is read to the structs either prints the printf's tests.". Please rephrase.

Comment: @Yunnosch i edited the post so I hope that now it is better.
About your second comment, when I run the project it appears "Run Succesfull" (i'm using netbeans) but the info isn't stored in the struct because when I can the function to print the struct, nothing is printed. 
In the "carregarStock" function the printf's that I have to test if it was read to the struct variables don't print anything either.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The context of how you call the shown functions is important. And you should do all the explaining within the question. So better [edit] it instead of adding infos in comments which belong into the question body.

Comment: Please read [mre] (...again). I get the impression that you are missing some essential parts of the concept.

Comment: Note that 'char ch;' cannot hold EOF.  Use int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a helper function to read out the two integers from one line.

```
bool get_two(FILE *stream, int* a, int* b) {
    return fscanf(stream, " %*[^,],%*[^,],%d,%d", a, b) == 2;
}
```

You then just need to call that 5 times.

Example:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int couroStock;
    int minStockCouro;
    int tecidoStock;
    int minStockTecido;
    int borrachaStock;
    int minStockBorracha;
    int cordoesStock;
    int minStockCordoes;
    int palmilhasStock;
    int minStockPalmilhas;
} Stock;

bool get_two(FILE *stream, int* a, int* b) {
    return fscanf(stream, " %*[^,],%*[^,],%d,%d", a, b) == 2;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("tabela_stocks.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        Stock s;
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); // skip first line

        if(get_two(fp, &s.couroStock, &s.minStockCouro) &&
           get_two(fp, &s.tecidoStock, &s.minStockTecido) &&
           get_two(fp, &s.borrachaStock, &s.minStockBorracha) &&
           get_two(fp, &s.cordoesStock, &s.minStockCordoes) &&
           get_two(fp, &s.palmilhasStock, &s.minStockPalmilhas))
        {
            printf("%d %d\n", s.couroStock, s.minStockCouro);
            printf("%d %d\n", s.tecidoStock, s.minStockTecido);
            printf("%d %d\n", s.borrachaStock, s.minStockBorracha);
            printf("%d %d\n", s.cordoesStock, s.minStockCordoes);
            printf("%d %d\n", s.couroStock, s.minStockCouro);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

If `tabela_stocks.txt` contains

```
Codigo,Produto,StockMinimo,StockAtual
1,Couro,300,1000
2,Tecido,250,2000
3,Borracha,200,500
4,Cordões,500,2000
5,Palmilhas,500,1000
```

Then the output will be

```
300 1000
250 2000
200 500
500 2000
300 1000
```

---

Since there are so many similarities between the different stocks in your `Stock` `struct`, you could break it down into smaller pieces and make a `struct` only holding information about *one* stock:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int stock;
    int min_stock;
} Stock;

bool Stock_read(FILE *stream, Stock *s) {
    return fscanf(stream, " %*[^,],%*[^,],%d,%d", &s->stock, &s->min_stock) == 2;
}

void Stock_print(const Stock *s) {
    printf("%d %d\n", s->stock, s->min_stock);
}
```

With that you could create a `Stocks` type like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    Stock Couro;
    Stock Tecido;
    Stock Borracha;
    Stock Cordoes;
    Stock Palmilhas;
} Stocks;

bool Stocks_read(FILE *stream, Stocks *s) {
    return
        Stock_read(stream, &s->Couro) &&
        Stock_read(stream, &s->Tecido) &&
        Stock_read(stream, &s->Borracha) &&
        Stock_read(stream, &s->Cordoes) &&
        Stock_read(stream, &s->Palmilhas);
}

void Stocks_print(const Stocks *s) {
    Stock_print(&s->Couro);
    Stock_print(&s->Tecido);
    Stock_print(&s->Borracha);
    Stock_print(&s->Cordoes);
    Stock_print(&s->Palmilhas);
}
```

and reading and printing would become simpler:

```c
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("tabela_stocks.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        Stocks s;
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); // skip first line

        if(Stocks_read(fp, &s)) {
            Stocks_print(&s);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Looking closer at the `Stocks` `struct` you may want to consider using an array instead:

```
typedef struct {
    Stock stocks[5];
} Stocks;
```

which would also simplify the rest of the code since you could loop over that array to read and print each `Stock`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. After reading your code, I redo my code replacing :
`fscanf(fp, "%d,%s ,%d,%d", &codigo, storeProduto, &minimo, &quantidade);`
for
`fscanf(fp, "%d, %*[^,],%d,%d", &codigo, &minimo, &quantidade);`
So the use of  `%*[^,]` solve it

Can you explain me what `%*[^,]` does?

Comment: @LuísOliveira You're welcome! `%*[^,]` is a non-capturing scan until a `,` is found. So it just skips ahead until `,`.

Comment: again, thank you for your explanation. All the best to you.

Comment: @LuísOliveira Glad it helped! You're welcome!